# Falha de segmentação em linguagem C

Tags: c, gcc

Oi, estou com um problema... O código só roda até uma parte depois aparece isso:

```
Falha de segmentação (imagem do núcleo gravada)
```

Segue meu programa abaixo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int seleciona_indice (int array[], int tamanho)
{
    int i, rnd = rand() % tamanho;

    for (i = rnd + 1; i < tamanho; i++)
        array[i - 1] = array[i];

    return rnd;
}

void embaralhar (char *array[], int tamanho)
{
    int i;
    char *aux;
    int *listaIndices = malloc (tamanho * sizeof (int));

    srand (time (0));
    for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
    listaIndices[i] = i;

    for (i = 0; i < tamanho - 1; i += 2)
    {
        int indiceA = seleciona_indice (listaIndices, tamanho - i);
        int indiceB = seleciona_indice (listaIndices, tamanho - i - 1);

        aux = array[indiceA];
        array[indiceA] = array[indiceB];
        array[indiceB] = aux;
        }
    free (listaIndices);
}

int main(void)
{

  char nome[23];
  int *data;
  printf("==============================\n");

  printf("          PARSENHA\n");

  printf("==============================\n");

  printf("Digite seu nome: ");
  scanf("%s", nome);
  printf("Digite sua data de nascimento: ");
  scanf("%d", data);
  embaralhar(nome, 23);
  printf("Senha forte: %s%ls" , nome, data);

  return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

O `gcc` gera várias warnings quando compila o seu código. Verifique as warnings e corrija.
Mas o erro está ocorrendo porque você está tentando usar um ponteiro inválido:

```
int *data;
```

em

```
scanf("%d", data);
```

O correto é declarar `data` como `int`:

```
int data;
```

e usar:

```
scanf("%d", &data);
```

Comment: obrigado! mas eu lembro que recebi um erro de ponteiros de char. pode me ajudar com esse erro tambem?

Comment: Não consegui entender o que seu código está tentando fazer.